# Python/TkInter pastes double things(such as a), because of keypress

Tags: python

I made a simple notepad in Python. It goes fine in all commands but Cut/Copy/Paste.
Here they are:

```
`def AppendSel(e = None):
    d = txt.get(SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
    frm.clipboard_append(d)
def Cut(e = None):
    AppendSel()
    txt.delete(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
def Paste(e = None):
    clipboard = frm.clipboard_get()
    clipboard = clipboard.replace("\n", "\\n")
    try:
        start = txt.index("sel.first")
        end = txt.index("sel.last")
        txt.delete(start, end)
    except TclError:
        pass
    txt.insert("insert", clipboard)`
```

When I select 'a', Ctrl+C, backspace, then Ctrl+V, it pastes 'a''a''a''a'. Where is my error so this little program can run fine?

**The real error I found:**Error is in keypress. TkInter detect each milisecond of pressing. How can I disable that?

PS: Kevin, that two chars are necessary for coding or else it doesn't accept Upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are appending to the clipboard with each cut, but never clearing it. Try `clipboard_clear()`. [Here is an example usage.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-July/030398.html)

Comment: #Fixed: Computer detects key presses each ms, so 2ms pressing is the problem. When from menu it behaves correctly.